# tokenizing sentences and counting the number in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame

```
index      sentences                                            category
1          the side effects are terrible !                         SSRI
2          They are killing me,,, I want to stop                   SNRI
3          I need to contact my physicians ?                        SSRI
4          How to stop it.. I am surprised because of its effect.   SSRI
```

I need to tokenize the sentence and then count number of tokens regarding each category. I know I can use the following code to do it. But I do not know how to count numbers of tokens.

```
df['tokenized_sents'] = df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['sentences']), axis=1)
```

any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as using the same apply method to count.

```
df['len_tokens'] = df['tokenized_sents'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```